# Style not getting applied to material CheckBox in Android

Tags: android, material-ui

I am trying to apply custom theme to remove extra space around checkbox using style.

But my style is note getting applied.

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
       android:id="@+id/checkbox"
       style="@style/TestCheckBox"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:visibility="gone"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/title"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       tools:visibility="visible" />

<!-- Style -->

   <style name="TestCheckBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
       <item name="minWidth">0dp</item>
       <item name="minHeight">0dp</item>
   </style>
```

Not sure what is going wrong

Comment: try  `<item name="android:minWidth">`

Answer (score 0):

This style add on your app theme

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <!-- .... -->
   <item name="checkboxStyle">@style/TestCheckBox</item>
   </style>
```